# How can I bundle Express Js (NodeJs) and Pug engine using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, server-side-rendering

**Introduction:**
I have used ExpressJs framework with node as server and pug as a template engine. I want to bundle .js , .pug & .css.

I'm aware of webpack *(module bundler)* configuration for static files *(CSR-client side rendering)* . For CSR appoach we will follow the steps below.

1. Bundle all files using webpack
2. Host html & bundle.js(created by webpack earlier) using server *(iis / npm serve or of any other choice)*.

So, I tried the same with ExpressJs which is(SSR-server side rendering), webpack bundled all files *(**excluding NodeModules**)* including index.js which contains server(nodeJs).

- Is it the right ? If so how to serve the files using the bundled host inside index.js?
- If that is totally a wrong then, can you please suggest some good practice?

[image: Folder Structure]

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');//cookie Parser
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');//JSON data

//Inbuild Functions
const userManagementRoutes = require('./src/routes/userManagementRoutes');
const app = express();

//view Engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './src/views/userManagement');

//for cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

// for parsing application/xwww-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

//Static File Server
app.use('/Malips', express.static('public'));

//Routes
app.use('/', userManagementRoutes)

//server
app.listen(3000);
```

src\routes\UserManagementRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const loginController = require('../controllers/userManagement/loginController');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('app.pug');
});

router.get('/Login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login.pug');
});

router.post('/Login', function(req, res){
    const { userName, password } = req.body;
    if(loginController(userName, password)){
        res.render('home.pug',{userName : userName});
    }
    else{
        res.render('login.pug',{errorMessage : 'Invalid Credentials'});
    }
});

module.exports  = router;
```

src\controller\userManagement\LoginController

```
module.exports = function LoginController(userName, password)
{
    if(userName == 'admin@gmail.com' && password == 'admin')
        return true;

    else
        return false;    
}
```

src\views\userManagement\Login.pug

```
extends _layout.pug
block content
    div 
    form(action="/Login", method="post")
        label UserName
        br 
        input(type='email', name = 'userName' required autofocus)
        br
        label Password
        br
        input(type='text' name = 'password' required autofocus)
        br
        input(type="submit")
        h3 #{errorMessage}
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

Comment: Why would you want to bundle server-side Node code in the first place? It doesn't make sense and isn't possible. Webpack is used to bundle client-side JS code modules into a single script because browser support for modules is not finalized yet. The only type of server-side bundling that I can see make somewhat sense is insert scripts and stylesheets as inline elements into served HTML files.

Comment: To be clear: your express app is a program written in JS and run by node (that just incidentally happens to reply to incoming http requests). It is not "served" in any way; it's just a bunch of scripts and resources sitting on the hard drive, being read and executed by node.exe. Nothing is gained by bundling it; to publish your server-side code you'd usually put it in a git repo, and those typically consist of dozens, if not hundreds of files.

Comment: @ChrisG I got your point. Sir, I'm a beginner in front-end dev. When I have learned CSR, its easily understood. SSR is a bit confusing for me. 
 
1. How can I make use of ES6 features and also bundling all javaScript files into a single unit(for minification - everything in a composed build) when I publish my application for prod? 

2. Why do we have 2 webpack configs (server, client) in react-ssr. Can we correlate these two > ExpressJs & > React-SSR.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Using ES6 features like `import` I assume? That can be done by enabling the flag or using a recent version of Node. Again, why do you want a "composed build" in the first place? *Why?* There's no reason to do that, not even for production. If you want a single script, just write all your express code in a single script. 2. Can you post a link to where react-ssr explains how to setup server-side webpack? The only thing that comes close is [this](https://github.com/oayres/react-ssr/blob/master/jsconfig.json).

Answer (score 1):

I found one way where the template engine(.pug) remains the same and only the Javascript will bundles.

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPugPlugin = require('html-webpack-pug-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'app-bundle.js'
    },


target: 'node', 
externals: [nodeExternals()],

module: {
    rules:[
        {
            test: '/\.(js|jsx)$/',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: '/\.pug$/',
            use: 'pug-loader'
        },
        {
            test: '/\.css$/',
            use: ['styles-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/views/_layout.pug',
        filename: '_layout.pug'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/views/app.pug',
        filename: 'app.pug'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/views/home.pug',
        filename: 'home.pug'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/views/login.pug',
        filename: 'login.pug'
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPugPlugin()
]


}
```